# Azure Timer Function is running multiple times on trigger

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have a timer function that runs every 12 hours that refreshes an oAuth token. For some reason the function run over and over many times resulting in about 3500 calls every 12 hours. Not sure if it is relevant but I have implemented the function in c# in Visual Studio and deployed to azure. My function does have an output binding to a azure blob for writing the refreshed token information. I thought originally that the problem was because I implemented the function as Async but the problem persists despite removing async.

Comment: Do you mean you see 3500 entries in invocation logs? Could you share timings of those invocations + your function definition?

Comment: With psychic debugging I found that your cron expressing in correct. If you share it, we can give your the right corrections.

Comment: Turns out that if a function is scheduled to run every 12 seconds, in 12 hours it will run 3,600 times: (5 calls per minute * 60 minutes per hour * 12 hours). So without looking at your cron expression, I have a feeling it might be setup incorrectly.

Comment: Here is the cron expression I am using. * * */12 * * *

Comment: I checked and it is not running continuously. It starts firing the trigger at the right time however it appears to fire the trigger every second for the entire hour.

Comment: Thanks everyone, you were correct I had the cron expression wrong. Should have used 0 0 */12 * * *

Answer (score 6):

Cron expression is wrong. I was using * * */12 * * * instead of 0 0 */12 * * *